# can Map store a class? "in this environment the sources for assign must be an object"

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to create a map of classes in react native. I am using Mobx as the store.

Here is the code:

```
getCoinData() {
    if (this.perCoinData.size > 0) return;
    this.pieData.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        const [ exchange, name, currency ] = value._id.split('-');
        this.perCoinData.set(
            key,
            new Coin(('_id': value._id), exchange, name, currency)
        );
    });
}
```

pieData is another Map which contains a string key and an object value. Coin is the class which I want to store instances of in the Map object. However, when the function runs, I get the error:

In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.

The reason I want it in a Map is because I want all of the key/values to be observable and I don't know the length of the object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're not trying to store the class, you're trying to store an instance of the class. (Or you would be, except there's a syntax error in your `new Coin` call unless Mobx extends JavaScript syntax in a very surprising way...) `Map` instances can certainly store objects. Whether Mobx has any issue with it (which seems **really** unlikely), I couldn't say.

Comment: Oops, silly typo. After correcting the type it seems I can store instances of classes, but trying to call one of the functions of the class in a forEach loop (i.e. key.function() ) gives me the error message "key.function is not a function"

Comment: The function wouldn't be on the *key*, it would be on the *value*.